# Update multiple labels based on selected view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am still trying to learn my way with Swift and right now I am struggling with how to implement something to look more like Swift:

Lets say I have a view which contains 7 buttons representing days of the week and 4 labels. Based on the selected day, these 4 labels will update with different data and have different colors.

For example I want to avoid something like this repetitive code, to have a method for every day:

```
   func updateMondayView() {
    label1.text = value1
    label1.textColor = value1 < 0 ? UIColor.red() : UIColor.green()
    .................................................................
    label2.text = value2
    label2.textColor = value2 < 0 ? UIColor.red() : UIColor.green()
}
```

In my head, I am thinking to have something like an enum representing the days and every day to take the values and color as arguments.

What does the community think about this ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: It depends on your implementation whether it's worth doing so or not, but whenever I see things like `label1`, `label2`, etc. I prefer putting them in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do in this situation is to attach the buttons from storyboard to one function. Then set the tag attribute on each button (1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday etc would make sense). Then in the function you can switch the tag attribute of the button.

The function would look something like this:

```
@IBAction func updateDayView(sender: UIButton) {

    switch sender.tag {

        case 1: 
            label1.text = value1
            label1.textColor = value1 < 0 ? UIColor.red() : UIColor.green()
            label2.text = value2
            label2.textColor = value2 < 0 ? UIColor.red() : UIColor.green()
        case 2:
            etc
        default: break

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For least repetitive code, I prefer to use Olivier's Idea (attaching function from storyboard to one function and using tags) and extension both.

You can add an extension for labels like this:

```
extension UILabel
{
  func foo(value1: String, value2: Int)
  {
    self.text = value1
    self.textColor = value2 < 0 ? UIColor.red : UIColor.green
  }
}
```

and use it in your function:

```
@IBAction func updateDayView(sender: UIButton) {

  switch sender.tag {

  case 1:
    label1.foo(value1: "label1", value2: 10)
    label2.foo(value1: "label2", value2: 15)
  case 2:
    label1.foo(value1: "label11", value2: 20)
    label2.foo(value1: "label22", value2: 25)
  default: break

  }
}
```